# Selecting text in a textField with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to dynamically set the value of a text field in Vuetify, focus it and selecting its text (in order for the user to be able to quickly reset the field if necessary). The error I get is "select is not a function". This works for normal text inputs, but does not with Vuetify text fields.

```
<template>
    <vContainer>
        <vTextField
            ref="input"
            v-model="input"
        />
        <vBtn
            @click="test"
        >
            Select
        </vBtn>
    </vContainer>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data: () => ({
        input: null,
    }),

    methods: {
        test() {
            this.input = 'test value';
            this.$refs.input.focus();
            // this.$refs.input.select(); -> TypeError: this.$refs.input.select is not a function
        },
    },
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `this.$refs.input` is not the underlying HTML input element. To get the input element do something like...

```
let inputEl = this.$refs.input.$el.querySelector('input')
```

Also, setting the `this.input` value and then attempting to immediately `focus()` and `select()` will not work. You'd need to use nextTick or setTimeout before attempting to `select()`. For example:

```
  test() {
        let inputEl = this.$refs.input.$el.querySelector('input')
        this.input = 'test value'
        setTimeout(()=>{
            inputEl.select()
        },200)
  },
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/TCtpH7T8kG)

Answer (score 14):

**An easy trick to select text in text field:**

```html
<v-text-field
    v-model="inputModel"
    @focus="$event.target.select()"
></v-text-field>
```